# Printing support in Flash

Tags: flash, silverlight

Is there is any printing support in  Adobe Flash like the new one in Silverlight.net beta 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash supports print for many versions.

you can start with this easy script:
http://snipplr.com/view/4942/as3-flash-printing-basics/

and find out more here:
http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/206/1/The-PrintJob-class/Page1.html
and here:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html

Enjoy!